# Receiving json in Java using a web service

Tags: java, json, service, web

I make a call to a server using Java in order to receive json information and I want to retrieve that information through a Rest Web Servie. Right now I have this code:

```
public class consult {
  public static void consult1() the url that retrieves json);
    InputStream response = url.openStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println(line);

            }
    reader.close();
}
```

This shows the Json perfectly on the console but how can I set the information into some variable so when I call this WS in my browser (/resources/consult/) shows the info according to this WS?

```
@Path("/consult")
public class ConsultJSON {

@GET
@Produces ("application/json")
public String getInfo() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
   return consult.consult1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you checking out this tutorial on how to implement RESTful JSON service:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/integrate-jackson-with-resteasy/

The idea behind the proper setup is that you don't need to return serialized string from your method. You just return a domain object and instruct framework to serialize it through annotations.

And of course you'll find there examples on how to POST new objects or updates for it (in JSON).

Comment: But I'm going to receive much more json information through this web service, I don't want to implement a Bean for each consult. I just want to return the json I already have.

Answer (score 0):

In reality you really should pipe the InputStream from the response directly to your OutputStream. There are facilities for doing this piping automatically in TUS in IOUtils / DataFetcher: http://tus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tus/tjacobs/io/